# java code to input data in GUI and create and validate xml file from the data

Tags: java

I need java code to make a gui which will take user input data,validate the data against a schema and the create a xml file from it.

Answer (score 0):

Sou You will need to learn:

Design patterns at least Factory,
DOM and SAX for XML handle 
SWING or AWT for gui.